# extension of regular logic

Tags: logic, category-theory, abelian-categories

The internal language of some categories (such as abelian categories) support only a fraction of first order logic. But every category can be fully faithfully embedded into a category of presheaves, and any such presheaf category is a topos and supports full higher order logic. If I am able to proof that some sentence $\phi$ using HOL and if $\phi$ is a sentence which is in the regular first order fragment of HOL, does then also $\vdash \phi$ hold in first order regular logic?

Is there some other way to exploit the embedding of a regular category into its presheaf category on a logical level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way of doing this is to embed regular categories into categories of *sheaves*.
We have the following fact:

**Proposition.**
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a small regular category and let $\mathcal{E}$ be the category of all functors $X : \mathcal{C}^\textrm{op} \to \textbf{Set}$ such that, for every regular epimorphism $p : A \twoheadrightarrow B$ in $\mathcal{C}$, $X (p) : X (B) \to X (A)$ is the equaliser of the evident parallel pair $X (A) \rightrightarrows X (A \times_B A)$.
Then:

- $\mathcal{E}$ is a Grothendieck topos.
- The Yoneda embedding $\mathcal{C} \to [\mathcal{C}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]$ factors through $\mathcal{E}$, i.e. every representable presheaf on $\mathcal{C}$ is in $\mathcal{E}$.
- The Yoneda embedding $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{E}$ preserves regular epimorphisms.

From the above fact we deduce that any sentence in the internal language of $\mathcal{C}$ as a regular category is true in $\mathcal{C}$ if and only if it is true in $\mathcal{E}$.
Here, it is crucial that we use $\mathcal{E}$ and not $[\mathcal{C}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]$: the Yoneda embedding $\mathcal{C} \to [\mathcal{C}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]$ does not preserve regular epimorphisms in general.
Since this holds for all (small) regular categories $\mathcal{C}$, we deduce that topos HOL is a conservative extension of regular logic.

Since you mentioned abelian categories, I would be remiss if I did not mention the Freyd–Mitchell embedding theorem, which is a much stronger result: it says every small abelian category $\mathcal{A}$ embeds as an exact full subcategory of the category of $R$-modules, for some (non-commutative) ring $R$ (depending on $\mathcal{A}$, of course).

Comment: "which is a much stronger result" Is it stronger in the sense that the fact you can embed conservatively an additive category in a sheaf topos can be deduced from it? Because when we take the topos of sheafs for the regular topology, we also get that *all* the "functions" we can define are automatically morphisms in the abelian category... This seems to be a strange situation! So for instance, when we build the connecting morphism in the snake lemma, we don't need to check it's a module morphism, only that it is well-defined...

Comment: Yes, there is a regular full embedding of the category of $R$-modules into a presheaf topos, so the result is stronger in that technical sense... but that is not what I meant. The embedding into the category of $R$-modules has stronger properties: for example, it preserves not only regular epimorphisms but also finite colimits. I think you will find it hard to build the connecting morphism in the snake lemma without embedding into an abelian category.

Comment: I believe that in an internal sense, finite colimits are also preserved in the topos completion: epis are preserved and the product $A×B$ is preserved, which is also the (internal) coproduct of the two abelian groups in the topos. Unless I make a mistake, the construction of the connecting morphism as presented [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_lemma#Construction_of_the_maps) for instance seems to work in the topos completion (and don't require coproducts anyway). Then we need only to check it is well-defined and it is automatically a homomorphism.

Comment: Yes, it is (also) true that you get an exact full embedding into the category of internal abelian groups in the topos of sheaves. It is not true that the forgetful functor from the category of internal abelian groups to the topos is full. It happens to be true for the representable sheaves. I'm not sure this trick is worth the effort to justify, though...

Comment: Hm, yes, moreover this construction works also just in regular logic...

Comment: how does the grothendieck topology for your category of sheaves look like?

Comment: It is described in the proposition. The condition is the sheaf condition.

Comment: @Zehn Lin Yes, thanks. It is generated by coverings consisting of single regular epimorphisms. The last puzzle piece that i need: how do i know that the embedding (into the category of internal abelian groups in the topos) is exact? i tried to show that it preserves coequalizers, but i am stuck.

Comment: It suffices to check that it preserves regular epimorphisms. A left exact functor between abelian categories that preserves regular epimorphisms will also preserve coequalisers.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Stupid of me. It preserves cokernels, but not coequalizers! It would be weird if it did, because the forgetful functor from the subcategory of abelian group objects in a topos does not preserve coequalizers.

Comment: You helped me a lot! Thank you :)